# importing specific worksheets based on months

Tags: vba, excel

I have this macro that import the required worksheets when I enter the section and year and months.
How can I add (from month) and (to month) to show the needed worksheets?

Thanks a lot

```
Sub macro()

Workbooks.Add
wb1 = ActiveWorkbook.Name

quantitiy_of_productions = "O:\LF\07M\JL\"

Section = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("w1").Range("Section")
Year = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("w1").Range("Year")
From_Month = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("w1").Range("From_Month")
To_Month = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("w1").Range("To_Month")

For i = 1 To 12

Filename = "QP_Sec" & Section & ".xlsx"
Workbook.Open Filename:=Quantity_of_productions & "QP" & Year & "\" &       filename, ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True

Workbooks(Filename).Close False

Next i
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere that i, From_Month or to_Month is used in the filename or folder or worksheet names.

Comment: i have 12 folders (months) and every month contain the files: ( "QP_Sec" & Section & ".xlsx")  (more than 15 sections). but I do not know how to let the macro open the required worksheets.
for example: when I fill the cells in excel:
section: 01 
Year: 2017
from_Month: 01
to_month:  05

the result must be: the files: QP_Sec01 ( but five files , I mean QP_Sec01 but from month:01 to month: 05

I hope that is clear
thanks